Is $\sin \theta$ in $\tan$ half-angle-form an identity? It eliminates solutions
Part A:
Consider the Half Angle identity for $\sin \theta$.
$$ \sin \theta \equiv \frac{2 \tan (\frac{\theta}{2})}{1 + \tan^2 (\frac{\theta}{2})} $$
When $\theta = \pi$, the LHS has a specific value, whereas the RHS is undefined and only has a limit. Therefore, is this still an identity? Aren't identities supposed to be identical for all angles?
Part B
Solving Sin and Cos trig equations by converting them to their Tan half-angle forms is a standard technique. However, I find that this technique can eliminate valid answers. Is this a well-known limitation mentioned in textbooks (year 11 and 12 level)?
An example:
Solve the following equation using the tan half-angle identities.
$$\frac{1 + \sin 2\theta}{1-\cos 2\theta} = \frac {1} {2} $$
$$\implies \frac{1 + \frac{2t} {1+t^2} }{1 - \frac{1-t^2} {1+t^2}} = \frac{1} {2}, \qquad t = \tan \theta$$
$$\implies \frac{1 + 2t + t^2} {2t^2}  = \frac{1} {2} $$
$$\implies t = \tan \theta = -\frac{1}{2}$$
This technique eliminated the solution that $\theta = \frac {\pi}{2}$.
Why did this technique eliminate $\theta = \frac {\pi}{2}$ as a solution? My guess is that it is because the tan half angle identity becomes undefined at this $\theta$.
Workaround?
Does it mean that whenever solving $\sin$ and $\cos$ trig equations by converting to their $\tan$ half angle identities, we have to explicitly check $\theta$ values that make the $\tan$ form undefined as solutions? Is this a workaround described in textbooks?

To say that's an identity is to say both sides are equal when they are both defined. For instance, take 1+z+z^2+...=1/1-z, this is an identity only for z with norm < 1, but the substitution is valid in this regime (and only in this regime). To answer the second question, yes, you have to explicitly check the values where the equality doesn't hold, as it's only valid to make the substitution for values where both sides are defined.

As others noted, identities are such only when both sides are defined. That said, as you noted, the RHS of the relation "only has a limit [at $\theta=\pi$]", which I take to mean: "although you can't substitute $\theta=\pi$ directly, you can take the limit as $\theta\to\pi$" ... which conveniently gives a value matching $\sin\pi$). The term-of-art here is "removable discontinuity". We allow limits to fill holes like this when necessary (and it's often necessary with trig identities). Instructors (myself included) can be a bit loosey-goosey about how/why/when we make such allowances.

During the derivation of that first identity, one divides top and bottom by $\cos^2(\theta/2)$, so certainly if $\theta=\pi$, this can't be done, so we would be stuck with the original half angle identity $\sin(\theta)=2\sin(\theta/2)\cos(\theta/2)$. You could still call your first equation an identity that is true whenever all quantities are defined.
As another example, $1+\tan^2(\theta)=\sec^2(\theta)$ is also an identity. That doesn't mean it's true for all $\theta$. It's an identity for all $\theta$ values for which the functions are defined.
I think this also answers your Part B question. Writing $\sin(2\theta)=\frac{2t}{1+t^2}$, where $t=\tan(\theta)$, assumes that $\theta\ne\pi/2$ from the start (really it assumes $\theta\ne(2n+1)\pi/2$ for any integer $n$), so you can never conclude $\pi/2$ as an answer.
Your workaround sounds good!
Edit: As a simpler example, suppose we want to solve $x^2=2x$. Of course we may divide by $x$ (as most students want to do), but that means we are assuming $x\ne0$. It's fine if you want to do it that way: you'll just need to check the $x=0$ case separately, and see that it is, in fact, a solution too.
